# Java 8 Lambda and Streams

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have the below piece of Code.

```
public static ModuleKey getDeployableModuleFromModulesList(List<Module> modules) {
        ModuleKey deployableModuleKey = null;
        for(Module module : modules) {
            List<Artifact> artifacts = module.getArtifacts();
            for(Artifact artifact : artifacts) {
                if(artifact.getType().equals("ear")) {
                    return module.getKey();
                } else if(!artifact.getType().equals("ear")) {
                    if(artifact.getType().equals("war")) {
                        deployableModuleKey = module.getKey();
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
        return deployableModuleKey;
    }
```

How can I achieve this using Java 8's lambda and streams ?

Comment: You should at least make an effort... Try to do it and show us where you're getting stuck! That's how you learn brother!

Comment: current implementation can return null. Not good. consider returning Optional<ModuleKey>. Or maybe ModuleKey.NONE (special null object).
Also, you always return either module.getKey() or null.

For lambdas, pseudo-code is `return module.getArtifacts().stream().map(module-> module.getKey()).map(key -> either null or key)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I may misunderstood the question: if you are looking for the first `'deployableModuleKey'` with `key='ear'` or `'war'`:

```
modules.stream().flatMap(e -> e.getArtifacts().stream())
  .filter(e -> e.getType().equals("ear") || e.getType().equals("war"))
  .findFirst().orGet(null);
```

if you want to find the first `'deployableModuleKey'` with `key='ear'` or last one with `key = 'war'`. probably two statements are required:

```
public static ModuleKey getDeployableModuleFromModulesList(List<Module> modules) {
    Optional<ModuleKey> op = modules.stream().filter(m -> m.getArtifacts().stream().anyMatch(e -> e.getType().equals("ear"))).map(m -> m.getKey())
            .findFirst();
    if (!op.isPresent()) {
        op = modules.stream().filter(m -> m.getArtifacts().stream().anyMatch(e -> e.getType().equals("war"))).map(m -> m.getKey()).reduce((a, b) -> b);
    }
    return op.orElse(null);
}
```

Update on 2/8, if you don't mind using my library: [AbacusUtil](https://github.com/landawn/AbacusUtil), the code can be simplified to:

```
Stream.of(modules).findFirstOrLast(
  m -> m.getArtifacts().stream().anyMatch(e -> e.getType().equals("ear")),
  m -> m.getArtifacts().stream().anyMatch(e -> e.getType().equals("war"))).orNull();
```

Comment: Nice that you found the inconsistencies in the old impl!

Comment: Thanks @user3380739. I want the second case.

Comment: When I am using the second code, the compiler is throwing two errors. One is `The method orElseGet(Supplier<? extends Artifact>) in the type Optional<Artifact> is not applicable for the arguments (() -> {})` and the other error is `The method findLast() is undefined for the type Stream<Artifact>`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the 'findLast' method is only supported in my own library AbacusUtil. update the answer to replace 'findLast' with 'reduce'

Comment: Can you please provide some explanation for your code snippet ?   Also, your code is returning an object of type `Artifact`. But it want to return an object of type `Module`. How would I do that ?

Comment: Also shouldn't it be `.filter(e -> e.getType().equals("ear")).reduce((a, b) -> b).orElse(null))` ?   I mean instead of `ear`, it should be `war`. Correct ?

Comment: How can I return the object of type `Module` instead of `Artifact` ?